# Applying a predefined excel function to a VBA for loop array to create a new function

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, switch-statement

I have worked with another programming language, but VBA is a relatively new platform for me. I know the algorithm I want to execute, but, I am having some issues with it.

I have been trying to create a financial model for market yield of a bond, and since in the natural process of things, I need to use a solver, I decided to go for the worksheet function IRR, with an array defined with FOR loop and case structure as shown here. I was just using IRR function within VBA earlier, and it showed the error- "Type Mismatch: Array or User Defined Type Expected".

However, now I do not see any error, but my function says that one of the arguments is the wrong data type. I should be very grateful if somebody could tell me what I am doing wrong here.

```
Function Market_Yield(Clean_Price As Variant, Number_of_Payments As Integer, Coupon As Variant, Face As Variant, AccIn As Variant) As Variant

    Dim Payment As Variant

    For i = 0 To Number_of_Payments

        Select Case i
        Case Is = 0
            Payment(i) = -Clean_Price

        Case Is = Number_of_Payments - 1
            Payment(i) = (AccIn / Coupon) + (Coupon * Face)

        Case Is = Number_of_Payments
            Payment(i) = ((Coupon * Face) - (AccIn)) + (((Coupon * Face) - (AccIn)) / Coupon)

        Case Else
            Payment(i) = Coupon * Face
        End Select

    Next i

    Market_Yield = Application.WorksheetFunction.IRR(Payment(), 0.1)

End Function
```

Comment: Can you show an example call?

Comment: We are not used to your financial vocabulary. Can you either avoid if, explain it or refer to an explanation?

Comment: And drop the () off Payment() as not needed.

Comment: Hello QHarr. Do you mean a snapshot of the output?

Comment: I mean some test values that reproduce the error. Minimal amount required to do so.

Comment: Hello Dirk Horsten. I apologize for the ambiguity. Basically, IRR is a single denominator term such that a number of future payments adds up to the current price.  https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/irr.asp   In the formula given, an r such that NPV = 0

Comment: Ah! Okay. Clean_Price = 60,485,100; Number_of_Payments = 23; Coupon = 4.25%; Face = 39,000,000; AccIn = 423,583.

Answer (score 2):

I made some changes to your code, it seems to work now?

```
Function Market_Yield(Clean_Price As Variant, Number_of_Payments As Integer, Coupon As Variant, Face As Variant, AccIn As Variant) As Variant
    Dim Payment() As Variant
    ReDim Payment(0 To Number_of_Payments) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Number_of_Payments
        Select Case i
            Case 0
            Payment(i) = -Clean_Price

            Case Number_of_Payments - 1
            Payment(i) = (AccIn / Coupon) + (Coupon * Face)

            Case Number_of_Payments
            Payment(i) = ((Coupon * Face) - (AccIn)) + (((Coupon * Face) - (AccIn)) / Coupon)

            Case Else
            Payment(i) = Coupon * Face
        End Select
    Next i
    Market_Yield = Application.WorksheetFunction.IRR(Payment(), 0.1)
End Function
```

---

Okay, why does this work and your macro not work?

1. You had declared `Payment()` as an array, but Excel doesn't like dynamic arrays, it needs there to be an upper bound.  So I added a line of code to `ReDim` the array to the bounds necessary;
2. You never declared `i`, you just started using it in a loop.  In most languages this would be fine, as you would do something like `for (int i = 0; i < Number_of_Payments; i++)` where the declaration is part of the loop.  But Excel VBA isn't like that, so you have to explicitly add `Dim i As Integer`;
3. Your `Case` statements were incorrect, as you were using an `Is` statement, and that's not how they work in VBA.  Because you use `Case i` at the top you just need `Case` and either a value or the keyword `Else` in the remainder of the statement, e.g. `Case 1` means "the case where i = 1".

I think that was about it?

Comment: For your sample data I get 0.014037.  Is this anything like correct?

Comment: YES! That is indeed what I need. Thank you Richard Hansell! Could you tell me what I was doing wrong?

Comment: Yes. I see now. Thank you!:-)

Answer (score 0):

Your Payments array is not initialized as an array.
This is why you get the error.

To create the array properly you should do this:

```
Dim Payment() As Variant
ReDim Payment(0 To Number_of_Payments) As Variant
```

Otherwise, it's not recognized as an array and the compiler doesn't know how large the array should be

Comment: Also `i` wasn't declared at all, and the `case` statements were a bit *weird*, etc.

Comment: I tried that, and I got an error saying something to the effect that the payment index should be a constant.